# if loops inside else block returns true instead of forced false

Tags: javascript

I have the following block of javascript code for a quick form validation:

```
    if(IsEmail(email) == true && name.length > 0 && sport.length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {

        if(name.length < 1){
            fields = fields.trim() + " Name, ";
        } 
        if(sport.length < 1) {
            fields = fields.trim() + " Sport, ";
        }
        if(!IsEmail(email)) {
            fields = fields.trim() + " Email, ";
        }
        alert("The following fields are invalid or missing: " +fields.trim());
        return false;
    }
```

For some reason the else block evaluates to true or it never reaches the alert() and doesn't return false. The form is submitted. If I remove the if statements, it does work as intended and returns false with an alert().

Any ideas?

Comment: check your error console.

Comment: Check your console. Also, (1) the `== true` is redundant; remove it, and (2) no need for the `else` if you return.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if with a **return** statement does not need a **else** statement. Because its just useless.

Only reason I can make out of your code above is **if** block is executed. In other words if statement is **true**. So flows not entering else at all. One way to be sure is to have an alert as first line for both if and else for debugging purpose.

Comment: I like adding `false` for readability. Maybe the OP checks his validate function to a boolean value. It isn't useless.

Comment: @A1rPun Sure it is. It's non-canonical and noisy.

Comment: @DaveNewton after spending some time figuring out what non-canonical is.. I still believe `return false` is the way to go.

Comment: @A1rPun ... The return isn't the issue, it's the non-specific equality to a boolean and the unnecessary "else" following a conditional that returns.